# Regular expression to replace "negative left parenthes"

Tags: java, regex

I hava a string consisting of a this rather messy mathematical expression

`String exp = "8+-(-74/2-(-(-(34+2)*19)))";`

In order to successfully parse the string and evaluate it, I need to replace every negative left parenthese with, say "!", resulting in: **8+!-74/2-(!!34+2)*19)))**.

To qualify as a negative parenthese/expression, the minus in front of the parenthese must be preceded by an *operator*, *the beginning of line*, or *another left bracket*.

So far I have come up with this

`exp = exp.replaceAll("([-+/*^(]|^)-\(", "$1!");`

...yielding me this: **8+!-74/2-(!-(34+2)*19)))**. Besides that, I have tried with pretty much everything.

Comment: This isn't really the way you should go about parsing math expressions. There are better approaches (e.g. shunting-yard or precedence climbing).

Comment: Yes, I actually use the shunting-yard algorithm! This is just for pre-formatting the string to simplify the parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the capture group into a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=[-+/*^(]|^)-\\(
```

And replace by `!`.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pY7nQ2)

the issue was that this capture group was consuming a character that you needed to identify the required parts to match. Using a positive lookbehind will not consume the match and thus, you don't need the `$1` in the replacement either anymore.

Comment: That did the trick. Guess I need to take a look at those lookbehinds and aheads :)